# Can i use 'alias' AS in CASE Statement PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, column-alias

```
SELECT 
    id
    , quantity
    , unit_price 
    , (antity * unit_price) as price    
CASE
    WHEN quantity * unit_price > 5000 THEN (quantity * unit_price) * 0.2
    WHEN quantity * unit_price > 3000 THEN (quantity * unit_price) * 0.15 
    ELSE null 
END 

AS discount

FROM OrderDetails;
```

I tried to use the alias `price` in `CASE` but it doesn't work.
In the above code, I repeated `quantity * unit_price` 5 times.
Do exist any better way to realize this code?
Is there way to avoid repetition in the CASE statement?

Comment: This is fine. You could also have a derived table (subquery in FROM), where you do the price calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a CTE

```
WITH CTE as (
SELECT 
    id
    , quantity
    , unit_price,
    (antity * unit_price) as price
FROM OrderDetails
)
SELECT 
    id
    , quantity
    , unit_price 
    , price    
CASE
    WHEN price > 5000 THEN price * 0.2
    WHEN price > 3000 THEN price * 0.15 
    ELSE null 
END 

AS discount

FROM OrderDetails;
```